# Access to Photos on iOS(Swift), have to try twice to get picture library to show up. It doesn't show up the first time, but show's the second time

Tags: swift, photosframework

I call the function. Alright

```
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    let index = viewControllers?.index(of: viewController)
    if index == 2 {

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        let photoSelectorController = PhotoSelectorController(collectionViewLayout: layout)


         let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: photoSelectorController)            

        present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return false }

return true
}
```

Photos not showing on first time

I have all of the right things asking for permission and everything..
I then call for the images with these functions. It works, but the second time I hit the button after canceling posting a post..
I'm not sure how to get the images from the library for the first call.
After that it works like a charm, but most users have been telling me this isn't a good experience , if they have to try twice.
I'm trying to reduce friction in the app usage.

It should show the pictures right after the user "Allows" the app access to the pictures so they can post, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong for it to show the pictures soon as someone grants access.

```
var selectedImage: UIImage?
var images = [UIImage]()
var assets = [PHAsset]()




fileprivate func assetsFetchOptions() -> PHFetchOptions {

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
 fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 100
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchOptions
}


fileprivate func fetchPhotos() {

   let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: assetsFetchOptions())

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        allPhotos.enumerateObjects { (asset, count, stop) in
            print(asset)
            let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
            let targetSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)

            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.isSynchronous = true

            imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, info) in

                if let image = image {
                    self.images.append(image)
                    self.assets.append(asset)

                    if self.selectedImage == nil {
                        self.selectedImage = image
                    }
                }
                if count == allPhotos.count - 1  {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “It should show the pictures right after the user "Allows" the app access to the pictures” Then that is the code you need to show. Permission request is asynchronous so it is not easy to do something immediately after it.

Answer (score 0):

If you `fetchAssets` before the user grants privacy access to your app, you'll get a `PHFetchResult` that's empty.

However, if before making that fetch you [`register`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/1620741-register) as a photo library observer, you'll get a [`photoLibraryDidChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrarychangeobserver/1620746-photolibrarydidchange) callback as soon as the user approves privacy access for the app... from that callback you can access an updated version of your original fetch result (see [`changeDetails(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phchange/2437203-changedetails)) that has all of the assets your fetch should have found. Then you can tell your UI to update and display those assets. (This is how Apple's [canonical PhotoKit example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575) works.)

---

Also, once you have a populated fetch result, ***please don't request thumbnails for the whole thing the way you're doing.***

Users commonly have photo libraries with tens of thousands of assets, many of which are in iCloud and not on the local device. If you synchronously get all thumbnails, you'll take forever, use tons of memory and CPU resources, and generate all kinds of network traffic (slowing things down even more) for resources your user may never see.

PhotoKit is designed to allow easy use in conjunction with UI elements like `UICollectionView`. A collection view only loads cells that are currently (or soon to be) on screen, even if you've told it you have zillions of items in your collection — similarly, you can request thumbnails only for assets that are visible in your collection view. Wherever you have your per-cell UI setup logic is where you should have your `PHImageManager` request. (Again, this is what the [canonical PhotoKit example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575) does.)

You can optimize even further by "preheating" the thumbnail fetch/generation process for assets that are *soon to be* onscreen. And then by managing your "preheating" to cancel such work in progress when further UI updates (e.g. fast scrolling of large collection) make it unnecessary. [`PHCachingImageManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phcachingimagemanager) does this. (And yet again, it's what the [canonical Apple sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575) does. Actually, that sample's a bit out of date, and as such does more work than it needs to on this front — it does its own calculation of what cells are just outside the scroll rect, but since iOS 10 the [`UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching) protocol manages that for you.)